# When would you want to use C#'s `new` modifier to shadow a method?

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism, shadowing

So the [new modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/new-modifier) shadows a method rather than override it...

I can think of near zero cases where that's useful and not confusing to the developers, maintainers and clients of the code.

What's a good example for actual use of this modifier to shadow a method?

i.e. an example that

- goes beyond printing a simple string to demonstrate what the modifier does,
- where using `new` as opposed to `override` is clearly favourable, and
- that isn't "I want to override something I'm not allowed to override" (because that's [a] just bad design and [b] leads to potentially very confusing code behaviour)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/ms173153(v=vs.110)?redirectedfrom=MSDN Yes, in practice, it is very rarely useful. The key thing to understand is that there are two aspects of `new`. a) Support for shadowing. b) The need to be _explicit_ about the fact that you are shadowing. b) is the main benefit - it highlights shadowing, without allowing you to do it _accidentally_.

Comment: Also see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/153738/what-are-some-practical-uses-of-the-new-modifier-in-c-with-respect-to-hiding and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/method-hiding-apologia (read the `GetEnumerator` bit in particular since it gives a great example).

Comment: I think you could use it to implement static count of e.g. enemies in a game, where Base.Count would be a total enemy count and Derived.Count would be certain enemy type count (and further some methods that interact with static counters or statistics or something like this)

Comment: @mjwills those are interesting links that address the question. One use case is during evolution of code when a method gets added to a base class (e.g. in an external API that I don't control) with the same name as a method I had already added in a derived class. The quickest fix is to shadow the method (although refactoring with a different name is probably better in the long run.)

Answer (score 1):

Almost all situations where I used shadowing had to do with generics. A problem that often arises with generics is that you want to add different generic types to a list. E.g.,

```cs
class Person {}
class Employee : Person {}
class Student : Person {}

class Company {}

class Account<T> {
    public T AccountHolder { get; set; }
}

var accounts = new List<Account<object>>();

// This does not work!
var empAccount = new Account<Employee>();
var studentAccount = new Account<Student>();
var companyAccount = new Account<Company>();
accounts.Add(empAccount);
accounts.Add(studentAccount);
accounts.Add(companyAccount);
```

To make it work, we create a non-generic base class of the account class

```
class Account {
    public object AccountHolder { get; set; }
}

class Account<T> : Account {
    public new T AccountHolder { 
        get { return (T)base.AccountHolder; }
        set { base.AccountHolder = value; } 
    }
}
```

And now, we can declare the list as `List<Account>` with a non-generic account class.

The `IEnumerable` / `IEnumerable<T>` interfaces use this approach. See [Reference Source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/ienumerable.cs,3acf01620172c7f0) (this is the current, open sourced implementation of the .NET Framework).

Comment: c# 9 changes this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/covariant-returns

Comment: @RandRandom, yes, this is a very useful feature that I missed, e.g., when implementing `IClonable` or  `IClonable<T>`, but it does not help in this case, because we have a getter and a setter.